# Tags of the week! April 15-21, 2019: Planning & Translation — RESULTS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

## WEEK: April 15-21, 2019
TAGS: [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) and [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)

At the start of this week [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) had 168 questions and [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) had 137. Let see how high we can get them by weeks end.

At the end of the week, [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) had 183 questions and [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) had 145.

---

As a followup to our [fantastic tag contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/announcing-our-contest-results?cb=1), and to suggestions that we [continue the fun](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/suggestion-continue-question-pushes/1955) in a more informal way, here is Writing.SE's third:

TAGS OF THE WEEK PROMO

This weeks winner was Monica with 2 question! She gets double points for managing to use both tags on a single question.

===

### Rules:

- The contest runs for one week, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or both of the tags of the week.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the week, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use both tags in the same question.

---

**Notes:**

- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this week's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal is to increase questions on tags that have not yet reached the magic 200 questions.  My personal focus is tags that are in the top 40 tags but under 200 questions.
- Others may take over other weeks and they may have different goals.
- Each week we'll have two tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

This contest is linked from [this Meta.SE post about topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327017/162102).  (Please update it for new challenges.)

Comment: So far by [searching for missing tags](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?page=5&tab=Relevance&q=planning%20-%5bplanning%5d) I've got [tag:planning] up to 178. There's probably more but I'll give it a break for now.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a week off for Passover.  :-D

Comment: @Cyn Not a problem. Enjoy the break. Maybe it will give you a chance to actually ask a question :P

Comment: I like your addition of putting the starting numbers.

Comment: Search tip:  Try this one instead.  https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=planning+-%5Bplanning%5D+is%3Aq

Comment: Are you planning to go for this coming week?  Or does someone else want to give it a go?

Comment: Okay, I just went ahead and did it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

Linksassin (1)

- [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) [How do I record information when planning to write a recap of events?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/44630/33442)

April (1)

- [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning)  [How much episode recap is necessary in a tv-focused podcast?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44640/how-much-episode-recap-is-necessary-in-a-tv-focused-podcast)

Liquid (1)

- [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) [English words in a non-english sci-fi novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44638/english-words-in-a-non-english-sci-fi-novel)

Monica (2)

- [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) [How can we make images with (necessary) text more translatable?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44659/how-can-we-make-images-with-necessary-text-more-translatable)
- [translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) [planning](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning) [How should we plan for translation when designing diagrams that require text?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44660/how-should-we-plan-for-translation-when-designing-diagrams-that-require-text)